# nvd3.js scaling xAxis by number of points in json (lineChart)

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I have 6 points for each series, but on xAxis are drawn 11 labels (adding 0.5, 1.5, etc):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vbid9x1gzb2qkgx/2013-11-06_1629.png

How to draw ticks only for existing points? I'd trying `chart.xAxis.ticks(6);` but it makes no effect

Comment: NVD3 has a habit of overwriting/ignoring things like these, so you may have to modify the source.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff In this case, _nvd3_ cleanly exposes the `xAxis` on the `chart`: https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/lineChart.js#L353

Comment: Yes, but as OP mentioned, setting the number of values that way doesn't work. Setting the tick values explicitly is a bit hacky in this case and won't work in general either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`chart.xAxis.tickValues([0,1,2,3,4,5])`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickValues) to explicitly set the values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But if there are too many points for each series, it looks awful. I can hide label on xAxis like this - `xAxis.tickFormat(function () { if (someCondition) return ''; });`, but there are unnecessary x grid lines - https://www.dropbox.com/s/1bpuraxao60f1f4/2013-11-13_1404.png

Comment: You can use some heuristics to limit the number of `tickValues` and you can use some clever CSS to remove alternating tick lines. However, such solution would work on an example to example basis only.